# Is an answer still considered plagiarized from another source if the only thing different is renamed variables?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I recently came across an answer that I debated flagging for moderator attention, because it appeared to be plagiarized from another source without attribution, *except* that all the variables had been renamed.

It was a new poster, so their code formatting was messy, but if you went line-by-line by the source I think I had identified, the lines were identical except for the variable names.

So, would this considered a plagiarized answer from an outside source?  Would this be worth flagging?

Comment: I'd say that is probably plagiarism. Time for an exception handler (aka mod) to step in.

Comment: Copyright violation and plagiarism do not require character-for-character or word-for-word identity, nor identical formatting. What constitutes a copy in the applicable (IP) sense is actually difficult to pin down, and the boundaries are established mostly by judges, but the case you describe does not seem to be anywhere near the boundaries.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I believe that in the US context, plagiarism is - except for visual art protected under VARA - not illegal, and so judges would have no say in the matter. Also, legal protections against plagiarism are not strictly an "IP" issue since *moral rights* are (I think) not considered IP. (American readers tempted to say without caveat that plagiarism is not a legal issue, please note that your country is unusual in this regard - in most jurisdictions, authors get both the "economic right" of copyright and non-transferable "moral rights", including a right not to be plagiarised.)

Comment: Just FYI, that's the crux of [Oracle v Google](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2018/03/googles-use-of-the-java-api-packages-was-not-fair-appeals-court-rules/) (where Google copied the function names and styling, but not the content)

Comment: Are people really arguing over PLAGIARIZING CODE?! As long as the code has no licence, no ownership claims, or contracts; well its considered free property.

You can claim ownership over a library of code (Like jquery if you own it) but you cant claim ownership over a simple like 5-200 character piece of code, as its so common in size, that anyone could make it.

Plus people, this is code, does anyone who codes REALLY follow those rules to begin with??

Comment: @Machavity Eh... without wading deep into politics, a lot of people - probably the majority of programmers, certainly including me - would object to characterising a from-scratch reimplementation of an API by people who did not even have access to the code of the original implementation as being meaningfully equivalent to copying and pasting code and then changing variable names.

Comment: Yes and no, @MarkAmery.  To the extent that there can be plagiarism without copyright violation, where the question of whether plagiarism has occurred arises outside the context of a legal dispute, you are right, a *government* judge does not decide the question (and to be sure, that is the sense in which I used the word).  But the question can come before a government judge, and otherwise settling such a dispute does require a judgment call from someone with the authority to make it.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm not saying I agree with it (copyright extended to such a granular level is detrimental to software development) but, so far, Oracle keeps winning that argument

Comment: I dont see the point in claiming ownership over small pieces of code, as it can be destructive to the future of all coding, because at one point, all tech tutorials would be useless, because some random kid claimed overship over it, code uploading would be a living nightmare

Comment: Are you trolling, @TaylorSpark?  Every single one of your claims is wrong, and yes, many people who code *do* follow copyright law and do conscientiously avoid plagiarization.  This is a serious issue both morally and legally, and violations can get you censured, sued (successfully), and / or fired.

Comment: Yeah yeah "sue a random kid online" for saying what you thought was wrong. Unfortunately, I havent done anything illegal, and what "claims" Have I made 100% true? Im simply stating my opinion.

Comment: I'm not threatening to sue you @TaylorSpark, I am trying to impress upon you that violating other's intellectual property rights can get you sued by the rights owner.  Moreover, your fear (or not) of a lawsuit should not be the principle governing whether you steal others' code.  Copying someone else's code without their permission is as wrong as taking their wallet, and taking credit for someone else's code is as wrong as taking credit for their artwork or their poetry (even, say, a 50-character haiku).

Comment: Who said I was taking credit for others code? LOL You obviously didnt understand it. I mean that we should be able to freely USE the code, not Sell it for some money or some stupid stuff, also if someone wishes to pull copyright sues on me, well I'm probably not in their country to begin with, and no Im not saying i'd steal someones work, I simply mean I dont care too much.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism):

> Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work.

If someone only renames variable names, that makes it *more* likely to qualify as plagiarism (specifically, misrepresenting as own work seems more likely), since he tried to obfuscate the fact that it was copied, in my opinion. Plagiarism isn't about word-for-word copying, it's about the idea/gist/etc, and is distinct from copyright violation in that way.

However, only changing variable names is probably copyright violation too if the original content doesn't allow copying without attribution.

Of course, keep *great minds think alike* in mind, if it's a short and simple piece of code it might very well be independently developed, so circumstance does matter.

Comment: I'd say that plagiarism isn't **only** about word-for-word copying. And plagiarism and copyright violation aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: "And plagiarism and copyright violation aren't mutually exclusive" – They are, in fact, orthogonal. If you hire a ghost writer to write your PhD thesis, then it's not a copyright violation (the ghost writer gives you an exclusive license to use the thesis under your name), but it is plagiarism. If you copy an entire book while giving full attribution, it is not plagiarism, but it is a copyright violation. If you do the same without attribution, it is both. On Stack Exchange, they are linked, though, in that CC BY-SA 2.0 only allows copying with attribution, thus plagiarism is …

Comment: … always automatically also a copyright violation, when copying user-contributed content from Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JörgWMittag " If you copy an entire book while giving full attribution, it is not plagiarism" Most definitions of plagiarism would consider this as plagiarism.  Using too much cited content, particularly without adding anything original to it, is generally considered plagiarism.  Although you are correct that you can violate copyright on something without plagiarizing it if you're using enough of it that it doesn't qualify as fair use, while not being so much that it's considered plagiarism.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "thus plagiarism is always automatically also a copyright violation, when copying user-contributed content from Stack Exchange" That's not true.  They could have been licenced to publish the content by the original author through some mechanism other than the CC license, in which they're permitted to publish it without citation.  The CC license doesn't restrict the rights holder from also granting more permissive licenses to others.

Answer (score 8):

I concur with [Erik's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386318/2988) that this is plagiarism.

It may, or may not, also be a copyright violation, depending on what the license of the original content is. (If it is from within Stack Exchange, then it definitely is, since CC BY-SA 3.0 requires attribution, and thus plagiarism is always automatically a copyright violation.)

There is actually another dimension in addition to the legal (copyright violation) and moral (giving credit to the author) ones. At least in academic circles, the reason why plagiarism is so heavily abhorred is that in the scientific method *traceability of ideas* is important. In order to investigate the merits of an idea, you need to know its context and its history, its "genealogy" if you will. Plagiarism obscures this.

This is also important on a Q&A site like the Stack Exchange network. Imagine, you discover a flaw in that answer, and want to correct it. With proper attribution, you can trace the code all the way back to the original source and inform everybody along that path of that flaw. Maybe the framework used changed its API, maybe the language deprecated a keyword, maybe a new framework that better solves the problem came out, maybe there is a security hole in the code.

Comment: Note that SO uses 'CC BY-SA 3.0 with attribution required' (rather than 2.0), according to the information at the bottom of this and every other SO page.